# logback configuration file -- write all except debug to file, as logging to console

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I ma trying to configure logback and slf4j to my eclipse. However, I am a bit confused about configuration file. I just want log output should be written to both cosole and file, but only debug information should be closed to be written to file. As a result, I have wrote some configuration file but it sucks, not even working. Anyway, how can I achieve this wish?

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.lordofthejars.foo" level="INFO" additivity="false">
   <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>

  <root level="DEBUG">          
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>  

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set level filter for fileappender to DEBUG

```
<configuration>

     <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
     </appender>

     <appender name="fileAppender1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
       <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <file>c:/logs/kplogback.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender1" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: in your code, where did you said file name in which log should be writtern

Comment: I have look at your answer but I donot understand where you did say that debugging log should not be written to file but should be seen at console.

Comment: That's what the filter is for: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#levelFilter

Comment: @Antony If you need to write all the logs to console except Debug, please add the same filter to console appender but with a small change. Instead of on match accept you replace it with delay and onmissmatch replace it with accept

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ThresholdFilter` filter:

> The ThresholdFilter filters events below the specified threshold. For events of level equal or above the threshold, ThresholdFilter will respond NEUTRAL when its decide() method is invoked. However, events with a level below the threshold will be denied

documentation: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#thresholdFilter

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
      <file>app.log </file>
      <append>true</append>
      <encoder>
         <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>

      <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
      </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```